# Why is Notepad++ so slow when dealing with files stored on a network share?

Tags: network-shares, notepad++

Recently Notepad++ seems to be very slow when dealing with files that are located on a network share.

I am editing small files (e.g. web.config) and it is slow to:

- Initially open a file on a network share.
- Switch tabs back to a file on a network share.
- Switch back to notepad++ after using another application.

My guess is when switching tabs back to a network file it tries to check if someone else has modified the file (I could live with turning this off and it could check on save).

I am on a "fast" local network and have only noticed this problem recently.

My local PC is Windows 7 Enterprise and the servers are Windows Server 2003 and 2008.

Comment: Was this ever figured out? I still have this issue and it is maddening since most of my work is done on files remotely

Comment: Using the solution provided by @Lex worked perfectly for me.  Kinda upsetting though cause I do like that feature.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but this actually happened to me again recently. I have had this problem in the past too. I keep forgetting to upgrade my copy of NP++ and that often fixes it. My organization prevents auto-update so I forget to do it myself too often.

Answer (score 25):

I ran into this exact issue. After asking around and doing some experimentation it seems to be related to Notepad++'s "File Status Auto-Detection" routines. I noticed that the more files from network shares that I had open the slower the UI would be to respond when receiving focus. I resolved this by disabling "File Status Auto-Detection". Perhaps not an optimal solution for all environments. Now I just wish there were a one button or keyboard shortcut option to check to see if the file has been changed since it was opened.

Comment: I have actually had this option disabled for a while now and it still exhibits the problem.

Comment: The third entry down in the File menu is "Reload from Disk".  Under Settings > Shortcut Mapper, you can bind that command to a keyboard shortcut.  I set mine to Ctrl - R so it duplicates the Refresh functionality I'm used to in web browsers.

Comment: Settings \ Preferences, then the MISC tab and uncheck Enable under File Status Auto-detection.

Comment: I have also had "File Status Auto-Detection" disabled for a while, and it doesn't help much at all.

Answer (score 0):

If tab switching is still very slow despite having disabled "File Status Auto-Detection", check whether you have the plugin **EditorConfig**.

Removing that extension solved the problem for me. More details on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-notepad-plus-plus/issues/39#issuecomment-888941556).

Answer (score 0):

Some VPNs block many TCP-IP & UDP protocols. Connecting via a UNC path tried to open a UDP connection which my productivity firewall (corp VPN) blocked - that froze NP++.

Mapping the UNC path to a logical drive in Windows Exploder (you heard me) and accessing it that way works fine, even with "File Status Auto-Detection" enabled.